# RestTemplate call returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-cloud, resttemplate, apache-commons-httpclient

**Background**

I am trying to consume a REST endpoint hosted on IBM Cloud API from my SpringBoot application using `RestTemplate`. I am using the following snippet to make the call:

```
RestTemplate send = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
headers.set("x-ibm-client-id", clientId);
headers.set("x-ibm-client-secret", clientSecret);

HttpEntity<BodyEntity> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyEntity, headers);

send.exchange(ENDPOINT_URL, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Object.class);
```

I used the following snippet to configure RestTemplate

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

**Problem**

Using this snippet, when the call is made I receive 401 Unauthorized. When I made the same call using Postman, I received correct response from server without any problem.

Since I received 401 response code I set to further investigate the request by logging headers and body and other parts of request.

I implemented `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to log outgoing requests to further debug the issue and added this interceptor to my RestTemplate config as follows:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    // new code
    builder.interceptors(new LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
    return builder.build();
}
```

After making the request again, I could see in the log that the outgoing call contained all details as it should e.g. Headers and Body were correct.

After this, I changed the whole thing to use Apache HTTP Client as follows:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

String reqString = "BODY";
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(reqString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));

httpPost.setHeader("accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
httpPost.setHeader("x-ibm-client-id", clientId);
httpPost.setHeader("x-ibm-client-secret", clientSecret);

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

try {
    System.out.println("Response status: " + response.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println("Response :" + entity1.toString());
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Using the snippet above, I executed the request and received correct response.

**Question**

Why RestTemplate call returns and error whereas HttpClient returns correct response?
Do I need to further configure RestTemplate?
What have I missed?